# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.0:run

Tags: java-ee-7, glassfish-4, cargo, maven-cargo, cargo-maven2-plugin

I'm using javaee7 sdk from [oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-sdk-7-downloads-1956236.html). I have faced a problem. When I enter `mvn cargo:run`, it stoped at `Resolved container artifact org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-core-container-glassfish:jar:1.4.0 for container glassfish4x` for a long time. And at last, some error occured: `Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.0:run`.

Here is my detail steps:

1. I download java_ee_sdk-7u2.zip.
2. I unzip it.
3. I move the glassfish4 folder to C:\glassfish4.
4. I use `cmd` to enter a console and `cd C:\glassfish4`.
5. I press `mvn clean`.
6. I press `mvn verify`.
7. I press `mvn package`
8. I press `mvn cargo:run`

At last, the console tell me `Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.0:run`, and here are the detail errors

```
[DEBUG] [en2.ContainerRunMojo] Resolved artifact and dependencies: [file:/C:/zjf/soft/apache-maven-3.3.9/repo/org/codehaus/cargo/cargo-core-container-glassfish/1.4.0/cargo-core-container-glassfish-1.4.0.jar]
[INFO] [en2.ContainerRunMojo] Resolved container artifact org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-core-container-glassfish:jar:1.4.0 for container glassfish4x
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Java EE 7 Samples Main Parent Project .............. FAILURE [14:17 min]
[INFO] Java EE 7 JSF Samples .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Annotated Enter Flow Sample ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Composite Component Sample ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Resource Library Contracts JSF Sample .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Custom Converter Sample ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Custom Namespace Composite Component Sample ........ SKIPPED
[INFO] Custom Validator Sample ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] DateTimeConverter Sample ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Enter and Exit Flow Sample ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] JSF Stock Sample ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Faces Flow JSF Sample .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Filesystem Resource Library Contract ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] File Upload JSF Sample ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] HTML5 JSF Sample ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Index Flow Sample .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Nested Composite Component Sample .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Override Renderer Sample ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Packaged Composite Component Sample ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Packaged Custom Converter Sample ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] HTML5 Passthrough Sample ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Scrumtoys POM ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Scrumtoys Entities ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Scrumtoys Flows POM ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Scrumtoys ManageStoryAttachments ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Scrumtoys Resource Library Contracts POM ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] Scrumtoys Red Skin ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Scrumtoys Yellow Skin .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Scrumtoys Orange Skin .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Scrumtoys JSF Sample ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Stateless View Sample .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Style and Layout Resource Library Contract Sample .. SKIPPED
[INFO] Use JAR-Packaged Composite Component Sample ........ SKIPPED
[INFO] Use JAR-Packaged Custom Converter Sample ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] View-based Resource Library Contract Sample ........ SKIPPED
[INFO] Java EE 7 REST Samples ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Message Board REST Sample Application .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Asynchronous chat REST Sample Application .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Java EE 7 Servlet Samples .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] annotation-war ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] async-request-war .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] dynamic-registration-war ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] multipart-war ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] session-cookie-config-war .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] jsp-resource-in-bundled-jar-war .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] servlet-container-initializer ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] servlet-container-initializer-war .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] servlet-container-initializer-lib .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] absolute-ordering-web-fragments .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] fragment1 .......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] fragment2 .......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] fragment3 .......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] absolute-ordering-web-fragments-war ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] non-blocking-io-read-war ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] non-blocking-io-write-war .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] http-upgrade-war ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Java EE 7 WebSocket Samples ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] WebSocket Auction Sample Application ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] WebSocket Draw Sample Application .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] WebSocket Echo Sample Application .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Java EE 7 CDI Samples .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Events CDI Sample Application ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Interceptors CDI Sample Application ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Guess CDI Sample Application ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Servlet CDI Sample Application ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] CDI Sample Application for TransactionScoped annotation SKIPPED
[INFO] CDI Sample Application for Transactional annotation  SKIPPED
[INFO] CDI Sample Application for Bean Validation ......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Java EE 7 JSON-P Samples ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] JSON-P JAX-RS Resources Sample Application ......... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14:33 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-12-07T23:19:37+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/174M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.0:run (default-cli) on project glassfish-samples-parent: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.0:run
failed: Error while expanding C:\Users\zjf\AppData\Local\Temp\cargo\installs\glassfish-4.0.zip
[ERROR] java.io.IOException: Negative seek offset
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.0:run (default-cli) on project glassfish-samples-parent: Execution default-cli of goal o
rg.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.0:run failed: Error while expanding C:\Users\zjf\AppData\Local\Temp\cargo\installs\glassfish-4.0.zip
java.io.IOException: Negative seek offset
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.0:run failed: Error while expanding C:\Users\zjf\AppData\Local\Temp\cargo\in
stalls\glassfish-4.0.zip
java.io.IOException: Negative seek offset
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: Error while expanding C:\Users\zjf\AppData\Local\Temp\cargo\installs\glassfish-4.0.zip
java.io.IOException: Negative seek offset
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.expandFile(Expand.java:148)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.execute(Expand.java:107)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.installer.ZipURLInstaller.unpack(ZipURLInstaller.java:355)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.container.installer.ZipURLInstaller.install(ZipURLInstaller.java:236)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.configuration.Container.setupHome(Container.java:793)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.configuration.Container.createContainer(Container.java:460)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.AbstractCargoMojo.createNewContainer(AbstractCargoMojo.java:719)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.ContainerRunMojo.createNewContainer(ContainerRunMojo.java:150)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.AbstractCargoMojo.createContainer(AbstractCargoMojo.java:630)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.ContainerStartMojo.doExecute(ContainerStartMojo.java:54)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.ContainerRunMojo.doExecute(ContainerRunMojo.java:86)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.maven2.AbstractCargoMojo.execute(AbstractCargoMojo.java:432)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Negative seek offset
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.seek(RandomAccessFile.java:555)
        at org.apache.tools.zip.ZipFile.positionAtCentralDirectory(ZipFile.java:403)
        at org.apache.tools.zip.ZipFile.populateFromCentralDirectory(ZipFile.java:271)
        at org.apache.tools.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:152)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.expandFile(Expand.java:137)
        ... 33 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

I known it's difficult to describe my problem. So I hope you can do the same steps as what I have done, then you will see the same problem. I wish someone can solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I know the problem. I should use `mvn install` instead of `mvn package`. Besides, after using `mvn install`, I should change directory to samples/servlet/annotation, then run `mvn cargo:run`. At last the right result will perform.

[The Correct Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ikx5A.png)